# Controller (or driver) causing Windows 10 to always stay awake

Tags: windows, drivers, sleep, game-controller

Ever since upgrading to Windows 10, my machine would not allow the screen or machine to timeout and sleep or hibernate. Before upgrading from Windows 7 the machine slept normally. After some searching I tried `powercfg -requests` but that did not result in anything listed as keeping the machine awake.

I later tried unplugging all of my USB devices and found that a Xbox Controller (PDP Afterglow Controller for Xbox 360) was causing the issue. When it is unplugged, the display and machine would go to sleep as expected.

With some further reading, I tried updating the driver to the latest Microsoft 360 Controller Driver `10.0.10240.16384 (7/9/2015)` since there is no specific Afterglow driver. While the controller continues to work, any time the it is plugged-in, the computer will not sleep.

The device (or driver I guess) says it supports power states D0 - 03, but it's always in D0 mode and seems to never drop from that.

Is there any way to change the power state of the device so I could run a script when the machine is idle and force the controller into D3 or D2?